# How can I integrate between Laravel and PhpStorm?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

Every time when I code on Laravel framework I get those IDE warnings.. like it didn't find some method or class like `Eloquent` Class.

I searched on google and I found [this plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7532) but it didn't help, actually I didn't see any difference.

Is it even possible to integrate between Laravel and PhpStorm?

Comment: check this out: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Comment: Also: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Laravel+Development+using+PhpStorm

Comment: PhpStorm doesn't know about Laravel's *facade structure* yet. That's why you get those *undefined class* errors.

Comment: There is a good laravel plugin for PhpStorm that *does* know about the facade structure. Open up plugins and install it.

Answer (score 1):

The video in the accepted answer explains it just fine, here is my text version:

on the command line type and execute:

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
```

next type and execute:

```
php artisan ide-helper:generate
```

This will generate a file called **_ide_helper.php** that will help PHPStorm/IntelliJ recognize the facades (add this file to your .gitignore as it is not part of your code).

Go back to your PHPStorm or IntelliJ and you will see that the facades are recognized and autocomplete is working!

Source code: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper